# Print numbers in range of two user-input values with while loop

Tags: c++, math, while-loop, range, cout

I feel like I might be missing something here, but something is telling me that I might just be making this more difficult that it has to be, but from the book, "C++ Primer, 5th ed.," I'm stuck on this problem:

> Exercise 1.11: Write a program that prompts the user for two integers.
>   Print each number in the range specified by those two integers.

Up until this time in the book, the only loop being used is the `while` loop, and no conditional expressions, like `if`, have been introduced. The problem would be simple if it were not for the fact that a user could put the values into the integers asked for in ascending or descending order, so simple subtraction WOULD find the difference, but without testing which way to increment.

How could I absolutely print the range between the numbers, guaranteeing not to just increment towards infinity without testing the outcome of such math and/or without comparing the two numbers? This is what I have; it works when the first value: `v1` is less than or equal to the second: `v2`, but not otherwise:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()  
{  
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;  
    std::cout << "Enter two integers to find numbers in their range (inclusive): "  
              << endl;  
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;  
    while (v1 <= v2)  
    {  
        std::cout << v1;  
        ++ v1;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It should be....`cin>>v1>>v2;`

Comment: min && max can also be implemented with avg(x,y)-+0.5*abs(diff(x,y))

Comment: Well, seeing as how you found the difference part of it, you can always use `std::min` to find the lower one and count that many numbers up.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, in practice this `0.5` will likely ruin the whole thing.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, I'd vote for either `>>` or integer division.

Comment: ((x+y) - abs(x-y))/2 and ((x+y)+abs(x-y))/2 will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple rewrite where you use `min` and `max` to determine the range you want to iterate on:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()  
{  
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;  
    std::cout << "Enter two integers to find numbers in their range (inclusive): " << std::endl;  
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;  
    int current =  std::min(v1, v2);
    int max = std::max(v1, v2);
    while (current <= max)  
    {  
        std::cout << current << std::endl;  
        ++ current;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

This also allows you to keep the two inputs "intact", because you're using another variable to iterate on the values.

Also note that the `++current` could be done on the exact same line it is printed if it was replaced by `current++`. The later would return the current value of `current` and THEN increment it.

**Edit**

Here's what Michael suggested I believe, in working code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()  
{  
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;  
    std::cout << "Enter two integers to find numbers in their range (inclusive): " << std::endl;  
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;  
    int increment = (v2 - v1) / std::abs(v2 - v1);
    int current = v1;
    int max = v2 + increment;
    while (current != max)  
    {  
        std::cout << current << std::endl;  
        current += increment;  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Well, first, it ill not print in reverse order (as the OP seems to want) and second, using `min` and `max` sounds like cheating to me ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I'm sorry but I don't see the OP asking for reverse order. Also, while learning how to program, I find it way more clearer to use standard methods like `min` and `max` than using a division to find out in which direction to "increment"

Comment: @ermartel, I do — `if it were not for the fact that a user could put the values into the integers asked for in ascending or descending order`. As for the clarity, it sounds more like an exercise than production code and I see `math` tag here… Helps to understand the nature of numbers, which is important in programming.

Comment: Yeah and sorry for unfortunate wording (about the direction to "increment"), my bad.

Comment: @emartel, I wouldn't go quite as far as to say, "cheating," but those parts of standard library weren't introduced yet. But yes, that is the outcome I wish to achieve.

Comment: Oh, you also added the code to illustrate my words. Thanks. That sounds at least close. I added the code to my answer (neither clear, nor efficient) to illustrate working around `v1==v2` case without using `if`.

Comment: @LouisC. check the 2nd version of the code, it's a "clear" version of what Michael was trying to tell you to do

Comment: @LouisC., and of course I didn't mean cheating as an attempt to offend emartel and his solution!

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, I see what you did there. I feel like I'm programming in perl: TMTOWTDI...

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker don't worry, I can still read smileys :)

Comment: @emartel, thanks, I was getting concerned, because I really didn't mean to offend you. And yes, I agree completely with the untypable abbreviation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(v2-v1)/abs(v2-v1)` or some such for increment. (provided they're not equal). And for loop condition you may check if current number is still in between, like `(v1<=v && v<=v2) || (v2<=v && v<=v1)`.

And to avoid the case of zero, I'd turn it into `do while` loop and use `v1!=v2 && ...` as a condition.

To sum it all up:

```
int v = v1;
do {
   std::cout << v << std::endl;
}while( v1!=v2 && ( (v1<=(v+=(v2-v1)/std::abs(v2-v1)) && v<=v2) || (v2<=v && v<=v1) ) );
```

P.S. I trust you can resolve the input issue mentioned in comments and in the other answer on your own.

Comment: I fixed it, thank ye kindly, sir. It looks like your formula would equal 0 for any values of v1 and v2... Care to elaborate?

Comment: @LouisC. Why would it? For 1 and 3 it would be `(3-1)/(3-1)==1`

Comment: And for 3 and 1, it will be `(1-3)/(1-3)==-1`.

Comment: (1-3) / (1-3) == 1 by the way

Comment: Which means I wrote some utter crap… hmm.

Comment: You simply need to divide by the abs to normalize your direction

Comment: @Mr. Kremlin, is abs() part of a library like <cmath>?

Comment: @LouisC., I'm not Kremlin, but yes.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker you're seriously suggesting this incomprehensible 4 liner to someone who's learning C++?

Comment: @emartel, Doesn't it sound like a good exercise in code reading? ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker no :P

Comment: @emartel, I disagree with you. Seriously though, I'm not sure I can quickly (at least) come up with a better solution for handling all cases and avoiding `if`.

Comment: @emartel, except for, maybe, spanning the condition in a few lines ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, *Works out algorithm on paper* Again, I see what you did there.... I do want to avoid the do clause, the `&&`, and the `||` operators, but that looks like fun, too. *Saves it for a rainy day.*

Comment: Yeah, I've had my fun ;-) To avoid `do while` you can do the plain while with exclusive interval and print `v2` after the loop, which is less pretty. How to avoid `&&` and `||` and still handle the `v1==v2` case I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys. I posted this because it's not simple with the tools I have learned about in the book (so far,) and I'm sure it'll seem like childs play somewhere around chapter three or so. How do I give you guys some cred' on your profile stats?

Comment: You've already accepted one answer, and the choice is fair — just because @emartel despite being a good sport has lower reputation. And you're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried my amateur way and got the result. I hope it will be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a;
int b;
int val;
cout << "Please enter small value "<< endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "Please enter bigger value than the last one " << endl;
cin >> b;

while (val>a)
{
    val = --b;
     cout << "The numbers between a & b are "<< val << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I still remember this problem from the C++ Primer, I think the way they wanted you to solve it was with the basics of programming they provided you until then.
In my opinion it should have been solved like this, if this was this exact problem from this book:

```
    #include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter 2 numbers" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    while (v1 < v2) {
        std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
        ++v1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with a solution based on my C++ knowledge (and two simple `if` statements) up to the point of that task in the book.

*Write a program that prompts the user for two integers. Print each number in the range specified by those two integers:*

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers: " << std::endl;

    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;

    std::cin >> n1 >> n2;

    if (n1 == n2)
    {
        std::cout << "No integers in between the numbers" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (n1 != n2)
        {
            if (n1 > n2)
            {
                std::cout << n1 << std::endl;
                n1--;
            }
            else if (n1 < n2)
            {
                std::cout << n1 << std::endl;
                n1++;
            }
        }
        std::cout << n2 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Peace!

Answer (score 0):

This could work for cases where the user can input any value for the range, and if you're only allowed while loops and boolean logic. Introduce a "Done" variable, and set to 1 if you enter the first while loop, which would skip the second while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int first, second, done = 0;
    std::cout << "Input two numbers: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> first >> second;

    while (first <= second)
    {
        std::cout << first << std::endl;
        first++;
        done = 1;
    }
    
    while (first >= second && !done)
    {
        std::cout << first << std::endl;
        first--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```